# Setting form element attributes

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZF2, I am rewriting a simple application previously writen with ZF1. I have a form wich I want to customize, because the default input/textearea width and heigth are not enought. Here my code for some fields of my form:

```php
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'page',
    'type' => 'Number',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Page',
    ),
));
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'Text',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Name',
    ),
));
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'notes',
    'type' => 'Textarea',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Notes',
    ),
));
```

How can I specify a width for my inputs elements, and the attributes cols and rows for my textarea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'type' => 'Text',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Name',
    ),
    'attributes' => array
        (
        'maxlength' => 250,
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => 'class-name'
    ),
));
```

You can add an attributes array, and specify a class which can be used to edit things like width for your input elements. I believe you can also add 'rows' and 'cols' to this as well.

Comment: I think this way is better, because my form don't need to know how to render it. The CSS will do the job :

`class-name input {width: 15em;}` and `class-name textarea {width: 60em; height:7em;}` => it works.